# Combinatorics- Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I am looking for an approximation of $S(n,n/2)$ where $S$ denotes the second stirling numbers. The wikipedia article gives quite a few approximations but they do not fit my problem. I now tried to Plot the stirling numbers $S(n,n/2)$ in mathematica for $n$ up to about 10000 and fitted them. This way I received $\log(S(n,n/2)) = 0.99n/2\log(n/2) + + 0.82n - 0.62 \log(n)$. This model fits pretty good however I have no idea how to justify it or how to approximate the value of $S(n,n/2)$ in another way. Thanks for any tips!!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at sequence $A007820$ in $OEIS$, there is an asymptotics by  Vaclav Kotesovec (2011) which write 
$$\left\{{2p \atop p}\right\}\sim\frac{2^{2 p-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-p} \left(\frac{p}{(2-z) z}\right)^p}{\sqrt{\pi }
   \sqrt{p (z-1)}}\qquad \text{where}\qquad z=2+W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)\approx 1.59362$$ Replacing $z$ by its numerical value, this gives 
$$\log\left(\left\{{2p \atop p}\right\}\right)\approx  p \log (p)+0.820761 p-0.5 \log (p)-0.658184$$

**Edit**

Repeating the curve fit for $100 \leq p\leq 5000$, what I obtained is 
$$\log\left(\left\{{2p \atop p}\right\}\right)=1. p \log (p)+0.820757 p-0.49903 \log (p)-0.663801$$

Comment: Hi Claude, thanks for your answer!! I looked up that new paper, however honestly speaking I have difficulties understanding the Notation there. He seems to denote the stirling numbers by $S_{n,n+k}$ making the approximation you mention above. However I do not unterstand that, as  $n+k$ can not be the second index of the stirling number, which should be less than the first

Comment: or is the second index my first index and then you make the shift $n \rightarrow n-k$?

Comment: Thank you Claude for the info about this sequence

Comment: You are welcome ! $OEIS$ is a fantastic place to visit, be sure.

Answer (score 2):

For large $n$, and for $v=n/m $ constant, 
we have  the following known precise asymptotic approximation (my deduction [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/163085/5428)):

$$ S_{n,m} \approx \binom{n}{m} \frac{(n-m)!}{\sqrt{2 \pi n (\lambda -v+1)}}
\frac{(2-\lambda)^m}{\lambda^{n-m}} \tag1$$

where  $\lambda$ is the positive root of $ \lambda = v (1-e^{-\lambda}) $  (explicitly: $\lambda=v+W(-v /e^{v})$ where $W()$ is the Lambert W function, first branch).

In our case, $n=2m$, $v=2$ and

$$ S_{2m,m}\approx \frac{(2m)!}{m!} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi m (\lambda -1)}}\frac{1}{(2\lambda - \lambda^2)^m} \tag2$$

with  $\lambda= 1.593624260040\cdots$. Plugging the Stirling approximation for the factorials we get

$$ \log(S_{2m,m}) = m \log m + \beta \, m - \frac12 \log(m)  + \gamma + o(1) \tag3$$
with $\beta =  -\log( \frac{2 \lambda -\lambda^2}{4})-1 =0.820760609$, and
$\gamma = -\frac12 \log(2 \pi \,(\lambda-1)) = -0.65818417389$

This coincides with Claude Leibovici's answer.

Some computed values of $\log(S_{2m,m})$ along with the approximation $(3)$:

```
 m    log(S)      approx     abs err
 10  29.408950    29.423980  0.015031
 20  74.166315    74.173807  0.007493
 40  177.879238  177.882979  0.003741
 60  292.198461  292.200954  0.002493
 80  413.371913  413.373782  0.001869
100  539.630815  539.632310  0.001495
120  669.937107  669.938352  0.001246
140  803.606351  803.607419  0.001068
160  940.152803  940.153737  0.000934
180 1079.213650 1079.214480  0.000830
200 1220.507505 1220.508252  0.000747
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia gives [lower and upper bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Lower_and_upper_bounds) $L(n,k)$ and $U(n,k)$ for $\left\{n \atop k\right\}$. For $k = \frac n2$, dropping some less-significant factors in $L(n,k)$, we get $$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2} < \left\{n \atop n/2\right\} < \binom{n}{n/2} \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2}$$
so
$$\frac n2 \log_2 \frac n2 < \log_2 \left\{n \atop n/2\right\} < \frac n2 \log_2 \frac n2 + n.$$

This confirms at least the leading term of your estimate, though we need better bounds if we want to improve it and get the coefficient of $n$ right: these bounds are genuinely off by a factor of $2^n \cdot \operatorname{poly}(n)$, which is why I take the log base $2$ above.

Comment: It already helps a lot, thank you!